# is x = b'ABC' equivalent to x='ABC'.encode("ascii") in python3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

Is `x = b'ABC'` equivalent to `x='ABC'.encode("ascii")` in Python 3.5? Are there any differences between these two methods.

Comment: For what it's worth, `b'ABC' == 'ABC'.encode("ascii")` returns `True`.

Answer (score 3):

They produce the same result:

```
>>> 'ABC'.encode("ascii")
b'ABC'
>>> b'ABC'
b'ABC'
```

However `encode()` will call the encoder at runtime, instead of at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

A quick test in Python 3 shows that they are indeed equivalent:

```
In [1]: x = b'ABC'

In [2]: y = 'ABC'.encode('ascii')

In [3]: x == y
Out[3]: True

In [4]: type(x)
Out[4]: bytes

In [5]: type(y)
Out[5]: bytes
```

According to the [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=lexical):

> Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater must be expressed with escapes.

Therefore, as long as all of the characters in the *unicode string* are ASCII, they will be treated the same.

Comment: You should emphasize that the only instance in which they are equivalent are the subset where all characters in the unicode string are ascii.

Comment: Also keep in mind an escaped character while technically represented by only ascii characters may still represent a non-ascii character that can't be encoded to ascii.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Yes, for your specific example, the two are equivalent in that they produce the same result.

However, for generic usage, they have some subtle distinctions. For example, consider the different ways they treat attempting to encode non-ascii characters:

```
@>>> b'Æ'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.
@>>> 'Æ'.encode("ascii")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xc6' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```